# MySQL query to create a rank chart over time

Tags: mysql, charts, rank, data-partitioning

I have a table with statistic data (roughly 100,000 rows) that has the following format:

```
WeekNum   Name     Value   Category
201751    Joe      15      X
201751    Max      23      X 
201751    Jim      7       X
201752    Joe      18      X
201752    John     17      X
201752    Max      31      X
201752    Jim      13      X
etc.
```

Now I would like to create a line chart with Google Charts to show the Top 10 over time. I want to create a JSON that then feeds the Google Chart API. The chart should look something like this:

[image]

How do I do the query to get the top 10 for each week? I came across some Rank questions here and adapted my query like this:

```
SELECT S.WeekNum, S.Name, S.Value, @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS Rank
FROM table S, (SELECT @curRank := 0) R
WHERE S.Category = 'X'
ORDER BY S.WeekNum, S.Value DESC
```

But this ranks all the records and I get back hundreds of records. Is it possible to get only the Top 10 for each week, and then do the ranking?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Do you want the top 10 per user per week, or just the top 10 per week among all users?

Comment: I want the top 10 for each week over the whole period of time. Each user has only one row per week.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT WeekNum, Name, Value, 
       @rn := IF( @week = WeekNum, @rn + 1, IF(@week := WeekNum, 1, 1)) AS rn
FROM mytable
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @week := 0, @rn :=0) As v
ORDER BY WeekNum, Value DESC
```

in order to simulate `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ... ORDER BY)` window function not available in MySQL.

Output from above query:

```
WeekNum Name    Value   rn
---------------------------
201751  Max     23      1
201751  Joe     15      2
201751  Jim     7       3
201752  Max     31      1
201752  Joe     18      2
201752  John    17      3
201752  Jim     13      4
```

Field `rn` returns the ranking value within each week slice. It is being reset for every consecutive week.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2f9d05/1)

You can now consume the results of the above query in order to extract the top 10 records for each week:

```
SELECT @rnk := @rnk + 1
FROM (
   ... above query here ...
) AS t1
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rnk := 0) AS t2
WHERE @rn <= 10
```

The above query uses `@rnk` variable in order to calculate the rank over all records returned by the subquery.

Comment: Awesome, that's it.

I used your first query and put the following wrapper around it. And that is exactly what I wanted:

       [SELECT WeekNum, Name, Rank FROM (
       SELECT WeekNum, Name, Value,... ORDER BY WeekNum, Value DESC) T
    WHERE Rank <= 10]